# Add width between table headers in Custom Table Form

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

Using Example from SO [Table Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62267539/react-table-v7-within-react-hook-form)

I successfully implemented the form in my component as per my need. The only thing bugging me is there is no gap between the headers and I can't seem to figure out on how to do that as it looks very odd.

[image]

As you can see in the highlighted it looks very weird  with no gap between headers.

[Working codebox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-hook-forms-solved-forked-jt5q1?file=/src/App.js)

Please do let me know if anyone figures out on how to do that.

I tried:

formtable.css:

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 30px;
  }
```

and it does provides space between header but it looks more ugly as header shifts to left and when clicking on add address inside form looks weird.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have not applied any styles. That says it all.

I have added some basic styling for your reference, you can style per your need.

Check the working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-hook-forms-solved-forked-vtv5n?file=/src/styles.css:0-362)

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

th,
td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

th:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}
td:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}
```